# instance has no attribute 'sock'

Tags: python, twisted

I have a basic server program running in Python using Twisted.  I am trying to reject a user and am trying to use `self.sock.close()`. When that line gets called I get an exception:

> AttributeError: IphoneChat instance has no attribute 'sock'.

This is strange because before this line of code was executing and not causing an exception:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, Factory
from twisted.internet import reactor
class IphoneChat(protocol):
   def connectionMade(self):
      self.sock.close()
      return
```

That is it right now I changed it when i was trying to reject a incoming connection.

Comment: We need to actually see some code before we can make any comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

self.transport.loseConnection() is another way to do self.sock.close() when using twisted.  I can not figure out why it was working and then stopped working.